# hyperledger fabric chain code installation

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

i am getting an error while i am trying to install my chain code on my peers 
i am using **Hyperledger Fabric**

[image] 
    var request = {
            targets: ["peer1.org2.example.com","peer0.org2.example.com"],
            chaincodePath: 'github.com/fabcar/node',
            // chaincodePath:'/opt/gopath/src/github.com/fabcar/node',
            chaincodeId: 'org2cc',
            chaincodeVersion: 'v1',
            chaincodeType: 'test'
        };

```
    let results = await client.installChaincode(request);
```

This is my function to install chain code 
I am using NodeSDK

Answer (score 0):

**chaincodeType** => Type of chaincode. One of 'golang', 'car', 'node' or 'java'. Default is 'golang'.

Better remove this optional field (*chaincodeType*) from your request and try again!!